# Error "Property [nom] does not exist on this collection instance" in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have two tables, `user` and `technicien`, with a one to one relation. When I edit a technicien using my form "Modifier Techicien" below I want the form to be autofilled with current information from both tables user and technicien.

At this time the form is autofilled with only information from technicien.

[image]

**controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $users = user::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],
['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])-
>with('users',$users);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    return redirect('technicien');
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts/app')
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $actif->id , $moyenne_avis->id , $users->nom , $users->prenom) }}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{$nom->nom}}" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Prenom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="nom" value="{{$prenom->prenom}}" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" value ="{{$moyenne_avis->moyenne_avis}}" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
                <input type="text"  name ="actif" class="form-control" value ="{{$actif->actif}}" >
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">

                <input type="submit" value = "enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: use laravel relationship to get nom data and you don't need to assign `$technicien` to multiple variable rather use only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Laravel relationships are set right you should just be able to do :

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = $technicien->user;
    return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],
 ['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])-
>with('user',$user);
}
```

And then in the view use $user->prenom, $user->nom.
Be aware that what you were doing up to now is load ALL the users in the $users variable and not only one!

This part looks really weird too :

```
return view('technicien.edit',['moyenne_avis'=>$technicien],
['actif'=>$technicien],['user_id'=>$technicien])-
>with('users',$users);
```

You can simply pass the whole $technicien and $user object and then access their properties from the view. Here is an example implementation :

**Controller**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //Get the technicien and the user associated with it (if the hasOne relation ship is set right)
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $user = $technicien->user;

    //return the view by passing a variable reprensenting the user and one reprensenting the technicien, you could probably access the user directly through the technicien also
    return view('technicien.edit')-
>with(['user' => $user, 'technicien' => $technicien]);
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    // do some request validation
    $technicien=technicien::find($id);
    $technicien->update($request->all());
    $technicien->user->update($request->get('user'));
    return redirect('technicien');
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@extends('Layouts.master')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h1>Modifier Technicien</h1>
        <form action="{{ route('technicien.update', $technicien->id}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        {{ method_field('PATCH') }}


            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nom">Nom</label>
                <input id="nom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[nom]" value="{{$user->nom}}" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="prenom">Prenom</label>
                <input id="prenom" type="text" class="form-control" name="user[prenom]" value="{{$user->prenom}}" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">moyenne Avis</label>
                <input type="text"  name="moyenne_avis" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->moyenne_avis ?? 0}}" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Etat Technicien</label>
                <input type="text"  name="actif" class="form-control" value ="{{$technicien->actif ?? 0}}" >
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="enregistrer" class="form-control btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: That worked well Thank you but just one thing i'm getting an error in relation with database updating when saving the edit "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException"
No message

Comment: Did you declare the 'update' route on your controller in your Routes.php file? You can copy paste the line where you declare the route for your TechnicienController here and we might find whats wrong

Comment: here is the route update     Route::put('/technicien/{id}', 
                                           'TechnicienController@update')-
                                           >name('technicien.update');

Comment: Try changing the "{{ method_field('PATCH') }}" in your view to "{{ method_field('PUT') }}" to match the Route::put !

Comment: Ok, you might really want to verify your controller name, the name of the method, maybe do a Log of the request, .. Something is off that prevents Laravel to match your request with the technicien.update route! You might want to try to do a "composer dumpautoload" in the command line also because sometimes changes to routes/controllers are not registered until you do that (try that first actually)